# Fastest, simplest way to handle long-running upstream requests for Django

Tags: python, django, multithreading, twisted, uwsgi

I'm using Django with Uwsgi. We have 8 processes running, and I have no real indication that our code is particularly thread safe, as it was never designed with threads in mind.

Recently, we added the ability to get live rates from vendors of a service through their various APIs and display them at once for the user. The problem is these requests are old web services technologies, and due to their response times, the time needed before the all rates from vendors are acquired (or it gives up), can be up to 10 seconds.

This presents a problem. We have a pretty decent amount of traffic on our site, and the customers need to look at these rates pretty often. With only 8 processes, it's quite easy to see how the server can get tied up waiting on these upstream requests. Especially when other optimizations need to be made to make the site baseline faster anyway (we're working on that).

We made a separate library (which should be mostly threadsafe, and if not, should be converted to it easily enough) for the rates requesting, and we can separate out its configuration. So I was thinking of making a separate service with its own threads, perhaps in Twisted, and having the browser contact that service for JSON instead of having it run in the main Django server.

Is this solution a good one? Can you think of a better or simpler way to do it? Should I use something other than Twisted, and if so, why?

Comment: Did you look at [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)? It's an asynchronous task queue that you could use to run the API requests as asynchronous tasks, with as many workers / concurrency you need. Particularly because you already isolated the worker code it should be pretty easy to integrate. It also features well documented integration with Django, and a nice job monitor in the form of [flower](https://github.com/mher/flower).

Comment: Async handler looks just right. Twisted might be an overkill, though. Look at gevent, which integrates with uWSGI nicely.

Comment: What makes a piece of software "overkill"?  Twisted doesn't significantly increase the disk or in-memory footprint of most Python applications.  Also we're still making more of Twisted so using it even for easy problems doesn't mean everyone will run out prematurely.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone A simple answer is the learning curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your code in-process with Django, you can simply call out to your Twisted by using [Crochet](https://crochet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which can automatically manage the creation, running, and shutdown of the reactor within whatever WSGI implementation you choose (presuming that it behaves like a regular Python process, at least).

Obviously it might be less complex to just run within the Twisted WSGI container :-).

It might also be worth looking at [TReq](http://treq.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to issue your service client requests; your new "thread safe" library will still have the disadvantage of tying up an entire thread for each blocking client, which is a non-trivial amount of memory and additional concurrency overhead, whereas with Twisted you will only need to worry about a couple of objects.